# TRY CATCH on a CONVERT in a Select Statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, try-catch

Is it possible to use TRY CATCH blocks in SQL Selects?

For stuff similar to this for example:

```
select 
   order, 
   CONVERT(DATETIME, orderDate)
from orders
```

What's the best  way of handling this scenario?

Comment: If IsDate is true, then you can cast it as a datetime.  That's the point of IsDate.

Comment: @JohnIdol: what do you mean by "standard".  ISO is of a standard for an example.  What are different formats there for orderDate?

Comment: sorry - I was getting confused - IsDate is fine!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't know about try-catch, but in SQL Server you have the ISDATE function and can there for do something like

```
CASE WHEN ISDATE(orderDate) = 1 THEN CONVERT(DateTime, orderDate) ELSE GETDATE() END
```

Comment: What if the Date Format is different?

Comment: My date fields are char(23) and doing ISDATE(datefield) = 1 returns no fields.  Their format is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm and I guess ISDATE doesn't recognize that.

Answer (score 14):

In MS SQL Server 2012 there is a new construct that does exactly what is asked for:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(float, 'test') IS NULL 
    THEN 'Cast failed'
    ELSE 'Cast succeeded'
END AS Result;
    GO
```

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx

Answer (score 3):

In the SELECT clause itself, no.

You can test for a date though using [ISDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx)()

```
select 
   order, 
   CASE WHEN ISDATE(orderDate) = 1 THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, orderDate) ELSE NULL END
from orders
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function ISDATE():

```
SELECT ISDATE('11/13/2009')
SELECT ISDATE('13/11/2009')
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a try catch is possible inside a select, but outside is possible when you're working with stored procedures.

```
begin try
    select cast(strartnr as int) from table
end try
begin catch 
    select 10000 from table
end catch
```